# Header has disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Simply put, [the header](http://sstatic.net/gamedev/img/bg-header.jpg) image on the main site doesn't load for me. I get:

> ## Server Error
>
> ### 404 - File or directory not found.
>
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I don't see it (I see the header image when I click your link); maybe it's been fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were seeing some static files not getting copied to all servers in the web farm.